# Windows 8.1 folder content thumbnail glitch

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, graphics

I have recently upgraded to Windows 8.1 (Preview then RTM with full format) and there's this annoying graphical issue where it messes up the folder content preview thumbnails.

[image: Image 1]

This can't be an overall problem because when I open the folder, the individual thumbnails look just fine.

[image: Image 2]

The icons were OK in Windows 7 and 8.0 on the same machine. I have an Intel HD 3000 (Windows Update Drivers) and GeForce GT525M (latest official drivers).

Please assist how to fix this problem...

Comment: I don't see where the glitch is they look exactly how one might expect.

Comment: see the pink/red artifacts and the unusually jagged edges around the icons, where transparency should be

Comment: Do you know which graphics engine is in use when this happens? Can you completely disable the GT625M and see if HD3000 does this or the other way around? It sounds like your computer might employ switchable graphics as well if this is a laptop.

Comment: it should be the Intel graphics as Windows Explorer will not use the nVidia GPU (yes, it's a laptop having Optimus graphics switching)

Answer (score 1):

This can not be fixed, **IT'S A BUG** and has existed since the very first version of Windows 8.1 came out. I however don't know how many are affected by this.

Below is a variant of the same bug,

This bug doesn't affect Windows 8.1 functionality but causes some icons to look ugly, distorted, fuzzy or whatever you would like to say.

This bug can be seen *(More Clearly)* in **"Delete confirmation dialog box"**. Its the dialog box which appears on screen when you want to delete an item in Windows. Since Microsoft disabled this confirmation dialog box in Windows 8 and 8.1, you'll need to first enable it with the help of following tutorial:

[Enable Delete Confirmation Dialog Box in Windows 8 and 8.1?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-delete-confirmation-dialog-box-in-windows-8/)

[image: Ugly Windows 8.1 Icon]

More here: http://www.winbeta.org/news/windows-81-bug-displays-ugly-distorted-icon-delete-confirmation-dialog

Comment: They probably had a reason to disable it, hah!

Answer (score 1):

Just <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and type in the search Folder Options.Click on the view tab and make to uncheck the box `Always show icons, never thumbnails`. This worked for me after I upgraded to Windows 8.1.

[image: Folder Options View Tab]

Comment: Can you describe the steps? This is a low quality answer as it stands, and I'd recommend using the [edit] function to add more information. Thanks

Comment: This is probably already unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the desktop>Personalization>Display

Make sure "Let me choose" Is checked, and select Medium... Experiment with different sized and check your icons each time.

Atleast this helped me...

Comment: wat? What do you mean by "Medium" and how desktop presonalization can do anything to OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be fixed as it is Windows generating these thumbnails. It doesn't treat the alpha channel of icons correctly when stretching them for the folder perspective.

Interesting however that you did not have this problem on Windows 7. I have the same issue on Windows 8.1 Update 1, but don't remember it behaving correctly on earlier versions.